# Ultisnips: autocompletion of (). Make snippet not expand again

Tags: plugin-ultisnips, snippets

I want to make a Ultisnips snippet for auto completion of `()`, `""`, `{}`, etc. I have <kbd>Tab</kbd> as my expand and jump forward key. My snippet is:

```
snippet ( "parenthesis" iA
(${1:${VISUAL}})$0
endsnippet
```

And it works great most of the times, but I sometimes have to write parenthesis or quotes without any text.

In that case I type `(` and then it expands as `()`, but when I want to go out of the parenthesis by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it expands the snippet again and I'm left with `())`.

I have no idea how to change this based on the documentation; is there an option to configure this behavior? Or how should I configure this snippet?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! When you *want to go you out of the parenthesis*, do you type `)` or some other combination? With the `$0` placeholder, I would expect you to be able to jump out using whatever keys jump between placeholders.

Comment: So sorry, i did put in in the question, but it didn't appear.  I use tab for expanding and jumping forward. I think this is the problem because ultisnips triggers the snippet instead of going to `$0` , but it is really convenient for me and i would like to know if there is a way to continue using it without changing the trigger key.

Comment: Ah, the duplication there could be an issue indeed.

Comment: Maybe there is a way to configure the snippet so that it only expands when there is no `)` right next to  `(`. Could I implement that?

Comment: If regex is allowed in the snippet, you could probably get to a negative lookahead

Comment: I really don't know how to do that, but I'll search it and try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I got it to work:

```
    global !p
    def mycontext(char):
        x = vim.current.window.buffer
        y = vim.current.window.cursor[0]
        z = vim.current.window.cursor[1]
        try:
            return x[y-1][z-1] + x[y-1][z] != char 
        except:
            return True 
    endglobal
    
    context "mycontext('()')"
    snippet ( "parenthesis" iA
    (${1:${VISUAL}})$0
    endsnippet
```

Comment: Are you by chance jfab, the OP? You should be able to use the same account if you wish.

Comment: I entered as a guest and now I cannot access the other account haha, sorry.

Comment: I'm *pretty sure* you can merge the accounts, if you wish. https://vi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts