# UltiSnips: how to avoid expanding twice in a row the same snippet?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I have this snippet for latex:

```
# theta --> \theta
context "math()"
snippet theta "theta" iA
\theta
endsnippet
```

My problem is that if I type `theta`, it is transformed automatically to `\theta`, but then if I press `<tab>`, it expands to `\\theta` which I do not want.

One solution could be to expand **only** automatically, and not when you press my `UltiSnipsExpandTrigger` key (e.g. `<tab>`). I have read `:h UltiSnips-snippet-options` and did not find a solution. I want to keep the `i` in-word expansion.

What can I do?

Related: [Ultisnips: autocompletion of (). Make snippet not expand again](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/29142/ultisnips-autocompletion-of-make-snippet-not-expand-again)

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Answer (score 0):

This context solves the issue:

```
global !p
def banned_before():
    x = vim.current.window.buffer
    y = vim.current.window.cursor[0]
    z = vim.current.window.cursor[1]
    banned_before = ('\\theta',)
    bufferslice = x[y-1][:z]  # contains the text before cursor of the current line
    try:
        return (not bufferslice.endswith(banned_before))
    except:
        return True
endglobal
```

```
# theta --> \theta
context "banned_before()"
# use `context "math() and banned_before()"` for both
snippet theta "theta" iA
\theta
endsnippet
```

Comment: It might be worth parameterizing the context so that `\\theta` is not hard-coded or specific to that single snippet.

Comment: Oh, I did not think of it, that's much better than what I did (keep a list of greek letters in my context function). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use a negative lookbehind regex, as in

```
context "math()"
snippet "(?<!\\)theta" "\theta" riA
\theta
endsnippet
```

The `r` in `riA` tells Ultisnips that the snippet trigger is a python **r**egular expression, and `(?<!\\)` says that we do *not* wish to match `\` before `theta` (we have to escape the backslash).